# Kendo DropdownList and ng-model doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, angular-kendo

I have a Kendo Dropdownlist bound to an ObservableArray/DataSource. It duly fills the values from array. But when I bind ng-model to a property, the dropdownlist fails to select the value.

HTML:

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list k-options="dropOptions" ng-model="user.id"></select>
```

JS:

```
var users = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' },
  { id: 3, name: 'C' },
  { id: 4, name: 'D' },
  { id: 5, name: 'E' },
  { id: 6, name: 'F' }
];

var usersDataSource = new kendo.data.ObservableArray(users);

$scope.dropOptions = {
  dataSource: usersDataSource,
  dataTextField: 'name',
  dataValueField: 'id',
  optionLabel: "Select one..."
};

$scope.welcome = "World";
$scope.user = { id: 3 }
```

`$scope.user  = { id: 3 }` should force dropdownlist to select C.

Here is link to Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BxTqWet5sz725ZtKEKJr?p=preview

How can I for dropdownlist to make selection based on value assigned in property bound with ng-model. I have used k-ng-model as well, but it doesn't work.  Please help me what am I doing wrong here. Thank you.

Edit: The selection in dropdownlist is not hardcoded. It will be fetched from database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using Angular 1.4.9 with Kendo v2015.3.1111. Downgrading to Angular 1.4.8 made it work.

Comment: I am having exact same problem during AngularJs update part of Angular migration. If i upgrade Kendo that would fix the problem. Unfortunately i can't downgrade AngularJs or update Kendo at the moment. Did you eventually find out what's wrong with it or found a fix? Apart from downgrading AngularJs.

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution that works.

```
  <select kendo-drop-down-list
         k-options="odsSoluciones"
         k-data-text-field="'descripcion'"
         k-data-value-field="'solucionId'"
         k-value="prescDPIntercambio.solucionDPId"
         ng-model="prescDPIntercambio.solucionDPId">
 </select>


$scope.odsSoluciones = 
     dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
         data: solucionesModel.data,
         }),
    };
```

In my case odsSoluciones returns an array with "solucionId" and "descripcion" fields and prescDPIntercambio.solucionDPId is the value I want to see selected

Comment: Bless you sir! This was so annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo dropdown value does not reflect selection based on ng-model. Instead it provides a new attribute : `k-ng-model`

For a basic example, have a look at this: [k-ng-model](http://dojo.telerik.com/oDaYo/2)

Comment: Did you check the demo plunker ?

Comment: Yes, I did check it yesterday.

Comment: Try by giving the options in the html just like the demo, instead of using k-options.

Comment: Thanks Ashfaq for your replies. Somehow Angular 1.4.9 didn't work with Kendo UI. I tried even Kendo v2016, but no success. Then I tried downgrading Angular to older version, the selection started working. I am gonna report this to Kendo.

Comment: That is strange though.

Comment: I am having exact same problem during AngularJs update part of Angular migration. If i upgrade Kendo that would fix the problem. Unfortunately i can't downgrade AngularJs or update Kendo at the moment. Did you eventually find out what's wrong with it or found a fix? Apart from downgrading AngularJs.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `k-value = "user.id"`to the template.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9Zfdu46ovFE3zTqDnL3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <h1>Hello {{ welcome }}!</h1>
  <div>Selected value is {{ user.id }}</div>
  <select kendo-drop-down-list 
          k-options="dropOptions"
          ng-model="user.id"
          value= 3
          class="glow"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: The value is not fixed. It will be retrieved from DB. I just used 3 for sample purpose.

Comment: You could use [get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and pass the result to value

Comment: My question is not how to set value. May be I am not clear. Kendo dropdownlist is not updating the selection based on value in property, `user.id`, bound using ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wierd situation where when I declare the ng-model as an object for example `$scope.abc.xyz = "test"`  ,the bind works whereas if I do `$scope.abc = "test"`  , the bind does not work.
Not sure what the issue is :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing the same problem. Try add `k-value-primative="true"` to dropdown list first.